# Is there is a way to send a local message from a Mac to an iOS device *without* the Internet?

Tags: macos, ios, terminal, notifications

I know I can send [Prowl](http://www.prowlapp.com) notifications from OS X to iOS, but that requires going over the Internet.

I'd like to accomplish the same thing, except that I want to be able to be able to do it *without* an Internet connection, to be able to send a message from a Mac to (an) iOS device(s) on the same LAN/Wi-Fi network.

*(It doesn't have to be with Prowl, it could be with any iOS app, as long as it can receive a message from OS X.)*

Comment: So - the OS X machine & the iOS device would be in the vicinity of each other?

Comment: @Scot - Oh, yes… I was assuming that they were on the same Wi-Fi/LAN, but realize that I didn't actually put it in the question. I have edited it to add that detail. Thanks for the question.

Answer (score 2):

If I understand you correctly you're asking how to push local notifications on your Mac to your iOS device (hence using Prowl as an example)? Well since Mavericks/iOS 7 if both your Mac and iOS device support Bluetooth Low Energy, you could use a service based on the [Apple Notification  Center Service](https://developer.apple.com/Library/ios/documentation/CoreBluetooth/Reference/AppleNotificationCenterServiceSpecification/Introduction/Introduction.html).
This feature is also covered in [this 9to5mac article](http://9to5mac.com/2013/06/13/apple-unlocks-full-notification-center-access-much-more-for-bluetooth-le-devices-in-ios-7/).

Comment: That might work, but my Mac doesn't do BT Low Energy.

Answer (score 0):

It is definitely possible to write an iOS/Mac OS application pair that would allow communication between the Mac and the iPhone using Bonjour on a local Wi-Fi network. Or using Bluetooth.

Though these might already exist, I'm not aware of any soft that does the trick.